# iOS Firebase Crashlytics Logs - Upload dSYM file to process them

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, react-native

My team and I are trying to get crash logs set up for our react native application.

The firebase console show the

> *This app has 1 unprocessed crash. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them.*
> error

- We have tried uploading the dysm manually by the drag and drop feature as well as by the terminal.
- On XCode, the build settings have been set to the DWARF with DYSM option.
- We have also tried to locate the the missing dysms via UUID by searching all XCode archives manually, as well as by running the

> *mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done*
> command in our terminal.

There are no matches.

The app has been uploaded to test flight. Under the build metadata section, there is no place to download the DYSM there.

[testflight metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v6Lm.png)

Crashes are able to be logged on Android, but iOS continues to provide problems.

Comment: Have you uploaded your app to TestFlight?

Comment: Yes, the app is on test flight. There is no option to download dysms in the build meta data section

Answer (score 0):

For manual upload to Firebase:

Via TestFlight dSYM Method

1. Upload your app to TestFlight
2. Download your dsym from appstoreconnect

Via Local dSYM Method

1. Locate your app archive, show package contents
2. Find dSYM folder and zip it

---

---EITHER---
3) follow the terminal command from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios

---OR---
3)Drag and drop directly to the firebase console(locate new feature)

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
The application is up on test flight, but there is no option to download the DYSMS from the build metadata tab, under "Include Symbols"

Comment: maybe it should finish processing? is this your first build? Check https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700051

Comment: Not the first build, no. We're deep in the first hundred now.
Even going back to previous builds doesn't show the option.

Comment: Mine show immediately so I can't help you any more.. you have to search for that. But if you do find a solution keep the thread live and post the solution

Comment: Thank you for your time. I do appreciate it.

Comment: @1es_miserables. Update: I encountered the same error on my upload today. go figure out;P. So after searching for a bit I found the dSYM files locally from my archived version, zipped them and drag and drop to Firebase console(new feature). Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, we had initially done that, but firebase wouldn't stop screaming at us about the dYSM. Eventually though, after we pushed the build to prod (knowing that it at least works on android), it just stopped complaining, and appears fully functional